# Sending private information to account owner

Tags: contract-design

I'd like to send an encrypted message, outside the blockchain, to an account owner who has previously interacted with a contract and whose public key is now known.

- Is there yet any existing infrastructure (contracts?) in place to do this
- Can I simply somehow encrypt the message with the public key and then the account owner can decrypt with the private key?